# How to print out all tabs for pages generated by rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to print out a page with .tabset enabled.

For example:

```
# **Tables** {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## Table 1

a table here

## Table 2

another table here
```

However, it only prints out the active tab.

I have tried something like this:

```
@media print {
    .tabs {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
<style>
@media print {
    .tab-pane {
        display: block !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
</style>
```

If you want the title of the panes to appear right before each pane, you can try the following script I wrote:

```
<style>
@media print {
  .tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* do not show tabset navigation */
  ul.nav {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* show headers when printing */
  .printhead {
    display: block !important;
    opacity 1 !important;
  }
}

/* dont show the headers on screens */
@media screen { 
  .printhead {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tabsets = $("div.tabset");  // get all tabsets
  $tabsets.each(function() {       // for each tabset...
    var tabNames = $(this).find("ul.nav-pills > li")  // get all the tab-pane titles...
                          .map(function() {
                            return $.trim($(this).text());
                          }).get();
    $(this).find(".tab-content > .tab-pane").each(function(key, value) { // and for each tab-pane, prepend the corresponding title
      $(this).prepend("<h2 class=\"printhead\">" + tabNames[key] + "</h2>");
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

It may need some refinement since I only tried it using your small example and Chrome but it might be enough for your purposes.
The result looks like this:

[image]

A reproducible example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
---

<style>
@media print {
  .tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  ul.nav {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printhead {
    display: block !important;
    opacity 1 !important;
  }
}

@media screen {
  .printhead {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tabsets = $("div.tabset");
  $tabsets.each(function() {
    var tabNames = $(this).find("ul.nav-pills > li")
                          .map(function() {
                            return $.trim($(this).text());
                          }).get();
    $(this).find(".tab-content > .tab-pane").each(function(key, value) {
      $(this).prepend("<h2 class=\"printhead\">" + tabNames[key] + "</h2>");
    });
  });
});
</script>

# **Tables** {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## Table 1

a table here

## Table 2

another table here
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works! There's only one minor issue. The headers (Table 1, Table 2, ...) for each tab are all at the very beginning (before 1st table), not at the beginning of each table.

Comment: Yes, that is the same sequence as they are found in the HTML tree. First a list of tab headers, then afterwards a container with the different tab contents. Im not sure how one could change that.

Comment: Updated my answer.